# Need assistance with frogger type game

Tags: java

I'm in the process of creating a frogger type game and have gotten pretty far in getting the program to do what I want it to do. However, I'm starting to think that to finish the game I will have to use way to much code and there must be a simpler way achieve the same results. I'm not looking for an answer, just need some more information.

Question 1: What can I use for the images that represent the moving Icons or cars? I'm currently using JButtons. The problem is that is difficult to get the buttons to move uniformly and I want to use 24 different moving Icons and from what I've learned so far I will have to add a new JButton for each icon.

Question 2: The way that I've gotten the Jbutton icons to move is to use a timer delay and then a counter to increment the x values. This works for the most part, but is there a better, perhaps simpler, way to move icons across the screen?

Any tips, tutorials etc are greatly appreciated.

Here is one of the classes that I've created to get movement of the icons:

```
public class EnemyJPanel extends JButton {

JButton enem = new JButton();
JButton enem12 = new JButton();
JButton enem13 = new JButton();
JButton enem1 = new JButton("1");
JButton enem2 = new JButton("2");
JButton enem3 = new JButton("3");
JButton enem4 = new JButton("4");
JButton score = new JButton("Score");
JButton enem5 = new JButton("5");
JButton enem6 = new JButton("6");
JButton enem7 = new JButton("7");
JButton enem8 = new JButton("8");
JButton yard = new JButton("50 Yard Line");
  int i = 16;
   int u = 576;
   int d = 16;
   int n = 576;
   int k = 16;
   int l = 16;
   int dummyval = 16;
public EnemyJPanel(){
    super();
      setLayout(null);
      enem1.setBounds(16,300,40,55);
      enem2.setBounds(16,245,40,55);
      enem3.setBounds(16,190,40,55);
      enem4.setBounds(16,135,40,55);
      score.setBounds(16,80,601,55);
      yard.setBounds(16,355,601,55);
      enem5.setBounds(16,410,40,55);
      enem6.setBounds(16,465,40,55);
      enem7.setBounds(16,520,40,55);
      enem8.setBounds(16,575,40,55);
      enem12.setBounds(16,300,40,55);
      enem13.setBounds(16,300,40,55);
      add(enem1);
      add(enem2);
      add(enem3);
      add(enem4);
      add(score);
}
public void addEnemy(){
     enem1.setBounds(16,300,40,55);
      enem2.setBounds(16,245,40,55);
      enem3.setBounds(16,190,40,55);
      enem4.setBounds(16,135,40,55);
      score.setBounds(16,80,601,55);
      add(enem1);
      add(enem2);
      add(enem3);
      add(enem4);
      add(score);
}
      public void enemyMovement(){ 
     i++;u--;d++;n--; // increments lateral movement from a timer in 
     dummyval++; // the dummy value is needed to keep the icons looping 
     dummyval = dummyval + 2;
     enem1.setBounds(i,300,40,55);
     i = i + 2;
     if (dummyval > 176){

     k++; k = k + 2;
         enem12.setBounds(k,300,40,55);
     }
     if (k > 176){
         l++;
         l = l + 2;
         enem13.setBounds(l,300,40,55);
     }
     enem2.setBounds(u,245,40,55);
     enem3.setBounds(d,190,40,55);
     enem4.setBounds(n,135,40,55);
     enem5.setBounds(i,410,40,55);
      enem6.setBounds(u,465,40,55);
      enem7.setBounds(d,520,40,55);
      enem8.setBounds(n,575,40,55);
     if(i > 576){ // resets button
         i = 16;
     }
     if(k > 576){
         k = 16;
     }
     if(u < 16){
         u = 576;
     }
     u = u - 2; // increase lateral speed
      if(d == 576) {
         d = 16;
     }
     if(n < 16){
         n = 576;
     }
     n = n - 5; //increases lateral speed


     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is created because you try to manage all the "stuff" separately. It looks like you may be missing some basic information on [classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html)
First, I would create a custom class, something like

```
class ButtonObject extends JButton
{
    public ButtonObject(String text, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        super(text);
        this.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

You also may want to take a look at [arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) and create an array of your new ButtonObject.

The [for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) will help you get through all the objects in your array.

```
ButtonObject[] enemies = new ButtonObject[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    String text = String.valueOf(i);
    int y = 300 - (i * 55);
    enemies[i] = new ButtonObject(text, 16, y, 40, 55);
}
```

There is probably a better way to do it than buttons but you may want to stick with them for now for simplicity.

Comment: I've tried something similar with the array; however, I was unable to add the JButton. Will the method allow me to do that?

Comment: Methods do not limit assignment of variables as long as the method has [access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) to the variable and isn't a static method (a method with the keyword `static`)